# XGBoost behaving deterministically despite subsampling and not setting seed?

Tags: python, machine-learning, xgboost, random-seed

It is my understanding that subsampling in XGBoost (version 1.7.4) is done randomly and so should introduce stochastic behaviour to xgboost - and so should stochastic gradient descent. However, when I train/test xgboost on identical data splits, I always get the same results despite not setting the random state anywhere, why is this?

I tried running the code with and without seed=42 when defining XGBoostRegressor. I did this for hand-picked data so that I would know that stochastic behaviour could only originate from the XGBoost model itself rather than from the variable data splitting.

Answer (score 0):

XGBoost indeed should give different predictions, when using subsampling in some form. This means that the attribute `subsample` should be different from 1.

I recently encountered something similar, I noticed that setting a global numpy seed was not sufficient. It should be done when calling the object `XGBRegressor`, and specifically setting the attribute `random_state = different seed`.

Please also check: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/524210/96626